# .NET Core 6.0 : error when adding new scaffolded razor page in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, razor-pages

I have been trying to add a scaffold item in ASP.NET Core, Razor pages using Entity Framework (CRUD). My current target framework is .NET 6.

I have the following package versions:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.7">
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.7" />
```

This is the instructions I am following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Here is my model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RazorPagesMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried repairing your installation ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: what version of visual studio?

Comment: Looks like you are missing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`.

Answer (score 2):

You added less  `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`  packages when you created the scaffolding of the Models, which is required for the scaffolding tool.

Package Version:

```
<PackageReference Include=" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design " Version="6.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.7">
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the installation order of those dependencies may affect their behavior. It shouldn't really. But in case it does...

The official documentation suggests that these dependencies may be installed in the following order in your project using Package Manager (from the *Tools* menu, select *NuGet Package Manager* > *Package Manager Console* or PMC):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

The preceding commands add:

- The EF Core SQL Server provider. The provider package installs the EF Core package as a dependency.
- The utilities used by the packages installed automatically in the scaffolding step.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-nuget-packages

Additionally, this is the content I have in my project file after the installation (at `MyProject.csproj`):

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```